# Assigning two different data types of array into an object array

Tags: java, arrays

I'm still fairly new to programming and I'm having a bit trouble with a program.

So to start, I want to create a program that would sort a pair of String and int. What's the proper syntax for it? from what I've search is that merge and ArrayUtil.addAll is way to do it but it doesn't work for me.

My code so far is this...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  int[] quizScore;
  int[] examScore;
  String[] names;
  int perfectQuizScore;
  int perfectExamScore;
  double[] quizGrade;
  double[] examGrade;
  double[] subjectGrade;
  int size;
    size = readInteger(0,100,"Enter number of students");
    quizScore = new int[size];
    examScore = new int[size];
    names = new String[size];
    quizGrade = new double[size];
    examGrade = new double[size];
    subjectGrade = new double[size];
    perfectQuizScore = readInteger(0,1000,"Enter the perfect quiz score");
    perfectExamScore = readInteger(0,1000,"Enter the perfect exam score");

    for (int x=0; x<size; x++) {
      names[x] = readString("Enter the name of student "+(x+1));
      quizScore[x] = readInteger(0,perfectQuizScore,"Enter the quiz score of "+ names[x]);
      examScore[x] = readInteger(0,perfectExamScore,"Enter the examination score of " + names[x]);
      quizGrade[x] = computeGrade(quizScore[x],perfectQuizScore);
      examGrade[x] = computeGrade(examScore[x], perfectExamScore);
      subjectGrade[x] = (quizGrade[x] + examGrade[x])/ 2;
    }
      System.out.println("\n\nPerfect Quiz Score = " + perfectQuizScore);
      System.out.println("\nPerfect Exam Score = " + perfectExamScore);
        showData(names, quizScore, examScore, quizGrade, examGrade, subjectGrade);
        double averageGrade = computeAverage(subjectGrade);
      System.out.printf("%n%25s%5.2f%n", "Average Grade =", averageGrade);
        double lowestGrade = findLowest(subjectGrade);
      System.out.printf("%n%25s%5.2f%n", "Lowest Grade =", lowestGrade);
        double highestGrade = findHighest(subjectGrade);
      System.out.printf("%n%25s%5.2f%n", "Highest Grade =", highestGrade);
      System.out.println();
      System.out.println("Sorted Record based on grades");
        parallelSortD(names, quizScore, examScore,quizGrade, examGrade, subjectGrade);
        showData(names,quizScore,examScore,quizGrade,examGrade,subjectGrade);
      System.out.println("Sorted Record based on names");                      
         parallelSortD(names,quizScore,examScore,quizGrade,examGrade,subjectGrade);
         showData(names,quizScore,examScore,quizGrade,examGrade,subjectGrade);
            System.exit(0);
        }
```

now what I want is a Object or a single array that would contain these arrays:

```
int[] quizScore;
int[] examScore;
String[] names;
double[] quizGrade;
double[] examGrade;
double[] subjectGrade;
```

Comment: To begin with you need to determine the programming language you use and set it as tag of the question.

Comment: Now you have to be clearer about the goal and about how what you tried failed to work (hint: a good question usually contains enough code for reproduction).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having now seen your code, I would make a Student class with fields for name, quizScore, examScore, quizGrade, examGrade and subjectGrade.
Add each of these to an array (or better, an `ArrayList`), and then sort it using a `Comparator`.

[This tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html) may help.

Answer (score 0):

If you're sorted pairs of Strings and Integers, and want to sort the Strings according to their Integer partners, then you can do it using a `SortedMap` rather than an array:

```
    SortedMap<Integer, String> map = new TreeMap<>();
    map.put(10, "ten");
    map.put(5, "five");
    map.put(100, "hundred");
    map.put(4, "four");
    System.out.println(map.values());
```

The result is:

```
[four, five, ten, hundred]
```

The `SortedMap` maintains its entries sorted in order of their keys.